# Git log shows multiple branches in commit?

Tags: git, logging

Running git log command gives:

```
commit 47e66ffc68af9daf680aa404d9b15f8f03daa123 (HEAD -> develop, origin/develop, origin/bugfix/xyz, bugfix/xyz)  
Merge: ee73887d4 ed24a4bd4   
Author: abc pqr <abcpqr@gmail.com>  
Date:   Fri Aug 23 16:03:51 2019 -0700
```

what does (HEAD -> develop, origin/develop, origin/bugfix/xyz, bugfix/xyz) this means ?
My local HEAD is pointing to local develop that is what I understood. what are other branch references signifies?

Comment: These branches all point to the same commit `47e66ffc68af9daf680aa404d9b15f8f03daa123` at the moment.

Comment: Thanks @ElpieKay for the precise and accurate ans.

Comment: @ElpieKay May you make this an answer?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

These branches all point to the same commit 47e66ffc68af9daf680aa404d9b15f8f03daa123 at the moment. They can be suppressed by `--no-decorate` if you don't want them to be printed.